# perl nested regex

Tags: regex, perl, perl-module, perl-data-structures

Text record:

```
(1,2,3,4,{fred,don,max,rat,grp},45,67,mat,jhon,{a,b,1,2,sd[{1,2},{4,5}],45,67,P[{34,56,34},{uni,cast,r}],c{q,ew,3,4},1,2,3,cf{2,4,5,8},6},4,fr{24,45,67},5,NOL)
```

Desired output:

```
(1,2,3,4,{fred:don:max:rat:grp},45,67,mat,jhon,{a:b:1:2:sd[{1:2}:{4:5}]:45:67:P[{34:56:34}:{uni:cast:r}]:c{q:ew:3:4}:1:2:3:cf{2:4:5:8}:6},4,fr{24:45:67},5,NOL)
```

needs to be replace by : for the below:

1. Everything between `{}` and `[]`
2. The data has nested structure like `{{}}` and `{[],[]}`
3. The text record is always between `()`.

Any help with perl is appreciated.

Comment: You should show some effort from your side also.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may try the below perl command which uses positive lookahead based regex.

```
perl -pe 's/,(?=(?:\{[^{}]*\}|[^{}])*})|,(?=(?:\[[^\[\]]*\]|[^\[\]])*\])/:/g' file
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kP3qU6/2)

Comment: Thanks Avinash...One issue is that the , is not replaced by : for a,b,1,2...........{a,b,1,2,sd[{1:2}:{4:5}],45,67,P[{34:56:34}:{uni:cast:r}],c{q:ew:3:4},1,2,3,cf{2:4:5:8}:6},4,fr{24:45:67}

Comment: Thanks Avinash, this works. I will load this for the complete data set.

Comment: I guess the downvotes come because you're helping someone who has shown absolutely no effort. I considered downvoting this answer (but I didn't).

Comment: Even high rep users also answereing these type of no effort question. We can't stop them unless SO takes some action on closing these type of questions immediately as unclear or too-broad (like dupe-hammer).

Comment: Apologies, i was checking via a handheld & i dont remember down voting. I ve corrected by upgrading but still shows -1. Will check with admin tomorrow.